# Javascript tell if scrolling div is being "held" with cursor?

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have a scrolling div with overflow:auto
And I want to scroll it by changing scrollTop, but before changing it I want to find out if the user is "holding" the scrollbar with his cursor, how do I do that?

Comment: This has got nothing to do with my code, All I am asking is a method to find out if the scrollbar is being "held".

Comment: Interesting enough I tried to determine what events were fired when a user clicks a scrollbar on a div a couple of days ago. I got absolutely nothing in Chrome v19. Not a single event, so this appears to be a lost cause unless you're interested in implementing a JavaScript scrollbar like jScrollPane (or something similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind your div to an event handler and then use a global variable.

```
var IsPressingDiv = false;

$('#DivID').on({

    mousedown: function () { IsPressingDiv = true; },
    mouseup: function () { IsPressingDiv = false; }
});
```

That way you could test to see if the mouse is being pressed down on the div. I'm not sure there's a way to handle mousedown on a generic scrollbar but if you needed to bind the events to the scrollbar I'd use a jquery scrollbar pluging or make my own.

Comment: You forgot the quotes around DivId :-) Btw, it's always a bad idea to use global variables. There is always a better way. Always.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: fixed the quote. As for globals, it's not ALWAYS a bad idea. Just be careful about a) what other code will be running in your page and b) choosing names that won't collide. Better option of course is to namespace your code.

Comment: The thing is, it is easily avoided in your example. Just wrap your code in an anonymous function and you're done. The only acceptable global is namespacing otherwise, indeed :)

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: think about this: global variables are closures on the window top-level scope. Besides, it seems the OP is not at that stage yet.